# Binning in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, binning

Example

Input have one column .

```
       Time
       02.10 
       02.40 
       02.50
```

Output

Since the 
Ave time difference is 20 min ((30 min+10 min)/2),

I need a data frame which buckets the data by average . 
It needs to add average time to first record , if the resultant time is there in data then it belongs to bin 1 , otherwise to bin 0. 
and then continue.

```
 Desired Output
    Time  - Bin
    02.10 - 1
    02.30 - 0
    02.50 - 1
    03.10 - 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question at first, thinking you want some sort of histogram of the `Time` column. Instead, it seems you just want to iterate `starttime + k * average_diff` and see whether those are in the `Time` column, is this right?

Comment: Yes. If the result is in Time column then it should belong to bin 1 otherwise bin 0.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? It seems like the first and last time will always be a `1`, the final item in the output never (because it is by definition more than the last item), and the items in between only in rather rare cases.

Comment: I am trying to build a time series . I need to achieve this as a part of it. That is a sample data I provided to understand . Actual data has huge number of records .

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always share what you have tried.

Anyways, try this. It should work

```
mean = df.Time.diff().mean()

start = df.loc[0, 'Time']
end = df.loc[df.shape[1] -1, 'Time']
len = int((end - start)/mean) + 1

timeSeries = [start + i*mean for i in range(len)]

df['Bin'] = 0

df.loc[df['Time'].isin(timeSeries), 'Bin'] = 1
```

This will create 'Bin' as expected by you, conditional, you create 'Time' properly as datetime.